# Saving previous value for later usage

Tags: java, math

I want to save a value and use it later to calculate the difference between prog and progalt.

```
int prog = (s3.getProgress()-90);
int progold = 0;
int i = prog-progold;
```

Then some stuff is happening. And after that i want to save the value of the actual prog in progalt to use it in the next round.

```
progold= prog;
```

Logically the "progalt = prog" will be useless, because progalt will always be set 0. So, how do initialize progalt once and then use the saved value?

Comment: what is `progalt` ? Did you mean `progold`?

Comment: Ups, yes I mean progold!

Comment: So what's the problem with `progold= prog;` this statement?

Comment: If the loop starts again progold will be 0 again. So how do I use int progold = 0; once and then "ignore" it.

Comment: Where is the loop. It's better if you add some more code snippet so that we can understand it properly

Answer (score 0):

```
int prevValue = 0;
while (someCondition) {
    int curValue = ...;
    int deltaValue = curValue - prevValue;
    ...
    prevValue = curValue;
}
```

Comment: And you may consider using of `static` if you want the `prevValue` will be shared by all instance by the class.

Answer (score 0):

As Rob had said above, you can set the value before any loops happen, and if you do not change its value within the loop, its value will remain the same.

```
int previous = 0;
loop {
  int current = ...;
  
  // Continue with logic using the value of last iteration
  
  // Set this iteration's value to *previous* to save it for the next iteration
  previous = current;
}
```

Because the variable *previous* was initialized and set to 0 before the loop began, its value will not be reset each iteration through.

- Get the current value
- Calculate with the previous value
- Set the current value to the holder variable, so that it gets carried over to the next iteration

Does this help at all?